# Shortcode do not return the right data in post

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, shortcode

Trying to make a CD plug-in. But cant seem to get the data rows in the shortcode.. i know it cant echo in a shortcode, but how Can i get, lets say a top 10 CDs in a post with a shortcode?

hope someone Can help with this..

```
<?php
/*
   Plugin Name: cd by dk
   Plugin URI: http://wordpress.com
   description: cd
   Version: 1.0.0
   Author: Rene
   Author URI: http://wordpress.com
*/

// Create a new table
function cd_dk_table(){

  global $wpdb;
  $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

  $tablename = $wpdb->prefix."cd_dk";

  $sql = "CREATE TABLE $tablename (
  id mediumint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  artist varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  album varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  year mediumint(11) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
  ) $charset_collate;";

  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
  dbDelta( $sql );

}



register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'cd_dk_table' );



// Add menu
function cd_dk_menu() {

    add_menu_page("cd", "cd","manage_options", "cd_dk_myplugin", "cd_dk_displayList");
    add_submenu_page("cd_dk_myplugin","All cd", "All cd","manage_options", "cd_dk_allentries", "cd_dk_displayList");
    add_submenu_page("cd_dk_myplugin","Tilføj ny cd", "Add new cd","manage_options", "cd_dk_addnewentry", "cd_dk_addEntry");



}





add_action("admin_menu", "cd_dk_menu");

function cd_dk_displayList(){
  include "list.php";
}

function cd_dk_addEntry(){
  include "add.php";
}



 function cd_dk2($atts) {


global $wpdb;
$tablename = $wpdb->prefix."cd_dk";

$cdcontent1 = "<table><tr>
<td>nr.</td>
<td>Artist</td>
<td>Album</td>
<td>year</td>
</tr>
";



  // Select records
  $cd_dk_entriesList = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$tablename." order by year desc");
  if(count($cd_dk_entriesList) > 0){
    $count = 1;
    foreach($cd_dk_entriesList as $entry){
      $id = $entry->id;
      $artist = $entry->navn;
      $album = $entry->station;
      $year = $entry->kontotal;

 $cdcontent2 = "<tr>
      <td>".$count."</td>
      <td>".$artist."</td>
      <td>".$album."</td>
      <td>".$year."</td>
      </tr>
      ";
      $count++;
   }



 }
$cdcontent3 = "</table>";
return "$cdcontent1 $cdcontent2 $cdcontent3";

    }





add_shortcode('cd_dk2', 'cd_dk2');
```

Comment: See [WordPress Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to find out how to develop a shortcode.

Comment: The code you've got looks OK at first glance. What specifically doesn't work? What do you see instead? Do you get any errors, on the website or in the server logs?

Comment: it only shows one row, with the number 2 in the first, and empty in the next 3 :( 
It should be showing 2 rows with artist, album and year